# What do the complex roots in the derivative $f'(x)$ say about $f(x)$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, complex-numbers, tangent-line

For example, take the function $\frac13 x^3 + x + c$.  Its derivative is $x^2 + 1$, which has no real roots, but two complex roots.  Looking at their graphs, it seems that non-real roots produce no horizontal tangent at all.  So I'm inclined to say that there's no implication at all, but maybe maybe there are features of $f(x)$ that I have not noticed.

Comment: But isn’t that indeed an implication?

Comment: If $f(x)$ has a multiple root then it will also be a root of $f'(x)$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField, it seems you're giving us a relationship between roots of $f(x)$ and it says about $f'(x)$, but the question is the converse of that with the qualifier *complex*.  Given a complex root of $f'(x)$, what does this root say about $f(x)$?  For example, a complex root $c$ doesn't say $f(x)$ has a horizontal tangent on the Cartesian plane.  I'm wondering whether there's more to it.  Maybe there are features of $f(x)$ that I have not noticed.

Comment: A notable result (the [Gauss-Lucas theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Lucas_theorem)) is that the roots of $p'$ (for a nonconstant polynomial $p$) will lie in the convex hull formed by the roots of $p$.

Comment: "Looking at their graphs, it seems that non-real roots produce no horizontal tangent at all."  -- Can you expand upon this?  What graphs are you considering?  For instance, if you write $\tfrac13 x^3 + x$ in terms of $z = x-i$, then you get $\tfrac13z^3 + iz^2 + \tfrac{2i}3$.  That looks like it has a horizontal tangent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give up on the idea of focusing on just the real-valued graph and think instead of the polynomial as a function with complex number inputs and outputs: a function $f:\mathbf C \to \mathbf C$. When $f$ has degree $n$, $f$ is locally an $n$-to-$1$ mapping *except* at the numbers $f(r)$ where $f’(r) = 0$.

For example, let $f(z) = (1/3)z^3+z$. Then $f’(z) = 0$ at $z = \pm i$, with  $f(i) = (1/3)(-i) + i = (2/3)i$ and $f(-i) = (1/3)i - i = (-2/3)i$. So for each $w$ in $\mathbf C$ other than $(\pm 2/3)i$, the equation $f(z) = w$ is $3$-to-$1$ near $w$: each number near $w$ is an $f$-value $3$ times. But this is false for the equations $f(z) = (2/3)i$ and $f(z) = (-2/3)i$, which each have just $2$ solutions. For instance,
$$
(1/3)z^3 + z = (2/3)i 
$$
is equivalent to
$$
0 = (1/3)z^3 + z -(2/3)i = (1/3)(z-i)^2(z+2i),
$$
so the only solutions of $f(z) = (2/3)i$ are $i$ and $-2i$.

This is a very important phenomenon in more advanced math, where it is related to ramification points or branch points of nonconstant holomorphic mappings between Riemann surfaces.

Comment: Could you clarify the notion "$n$-to-1"?  Do you mean that there are $n$ numbers $z$ that get mapped to the same $f(z)$?

Comment: @user1145880  it means each value in the target space is taken on $n$ times from the domain. For example, squaring as a function $\mathbf C^\times \to \mathbf C^\times$ is $2$-to-$1$, but if we extend squaring to include the value $0$ then the pattern breaks because $0$ is the square of just one complex number, not two of them.  The squaring map is ramified at $0$.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much.